JVM parallel processing with streams or threadpool does not really work
So we are testing out parallel streams and so far they do not yield any performance boost at all on a 8 core machine.
Optional<Swap> ret = Arrays.stream( a ).parallel()
.mapToObj( source -> { some very heavy number crunching } )
.min( Comparator.comparing( s -> s.valueDelta ) );

The array a has length 4 and holds the number 0...3.
I can ".peek()" and print the thread and see that it is using 4 threads running.
The runtime is a bit slower than subsitituting the stream by a sequential for loop iterating over a.
The number crunching has no io, no interaction or synchronization and access only read-only data structure to determine a best value "swap".
Just as an experiment, i subsituted my number crunching ith a sleep(2000) and the whole thing terminated after 2039ms, so it seems to run in parallel. But the number crunching does not speed up at all.
Looking with process explorer and resource monitor on windows it seems it only utilizes one core.
So i tried running it on linux and didn't get any better results.
For some reason jvm is not properly utilizing the available cores with its threading.
We can reprdouce this on multiple machines, windows and linux and no one ever got any speed up.
As an alternative i also implemented it using a fixed threadpool with size 4 and again, no speed up what so ever while 4 threads are showns running (i print from within the tread for debugging to see if i have different thread in parallel printing something).
Any idea?
EDIT Updates after some more testing:
I have some more insights after thourough testing:
You can reporoduce it by doing the following as "number crunshing". I used 4 array lists whici i shuffeled and sorted (this is an analog of my code as i used some other list types).
Optional<Integer> ret = Arrays.stream( arrayOfLists ).parallel()
.mapToObj( list-> {
    Collections.shuffle( list );
    list.sort( comparator );
    return list.get(0);
 } )
.min();

Now, if the shuffling and sorting of one lists takes less than, say 30s, i do not see any improvement with parallization. So basically no matter if i parallelize, they take 2 minutes till done.
But if i make the lists long enough, say 1 000 000 elements, then i start seeing some speed up. If i recall right, sequentially the four lists take around 7 minutes and with 4 threads or parallel streams around 5 (also using 4 threads as i have checked).
Don't beat me on the exact time numbers... was something around that.
Now the reason for that seems to be that the OS (windows and linux) is not considering the workload high enough to move the threads on different cores, which is insane.
If i do not have lists so big that they take near a minute all the work is only done by one core, while the rest of my 8 core cpu is sleeping.
Now in my original problem i was partitioning a graph for minimal crossing edges (multiple partitions) using a derivate of Lin-Kernighan.
The evaluation of all possible moves can be easiy split into disjoint operations per starting partition of the swap.
So i wanted to parellize that. But because that work takes for all (in my case( 4 partitions ) around 1.5s, the os refuses to parellize my JVM threads and so i end up with 0 speed up.
And that is totally insane because the whole algorithm runs on around 18000 nnodes and takes in total around 5 to 10 minutes.
Almost 20 years ago OS's scheduled smarter. I did my master thesis on realistic performance prediction of parallel algorithms and you could get almost linear speed ups for independend problems of VERY small sizes then.
The question now is:
Are the OS schedulers doing this non-sense only with java VMs or is this now a general regression on scheduling?
Is there something i can do about it? It basically screws up a lot of parellel algorithms by refusing to actually run them in parallel.

How long does the number crunching take without parallelization?  If it is sufficiently fast, this would not be surprising at all, but if it takes a while it's at least a little surprising.

When I ran my own tests I noticed that small arrays like yours are not processed in parallel.

maybe one or more [mre] would be helpful

I updated my post with new info and an example.

@DuncG Then use a fix threadpool and executor service. The observed problem happens with that as well.
But in my case streams is parellizing even an array with two elements wich it obviously should.

your last example is strange - mapToObj() is only available (AFAIK) on streams of primitives -- probably meant to be mapToInt (for min())

No, it is mapToObj as it is a stream of primitives. The min though could be wrong as in the original it was min of an object. But it doesn't matter. Just make a parallek stream of 4 lists and shuffle and sort them. I posted a skelleton. It happens all the time with stream and with executor pools as i described above.
And it shouldn't. It is beyond absurd that the system refuses to prallelize things that take only a second or even more. Many algorithms rely on prallizing even smaller workloads while they repeat that thousands of times. And this was not the case two decades ago.

so arrayOfLists is not an array containing lists?!? I assumed it was, based on its name and context. That is, I assumed it is an array containing lists; that would mean that Arrays.stream( arrayOfLists ) returns a Stream<List> and such does not have a mapToObj() method. I also wonder how list-> { Collections.shuffle( list ); list.sort( comparator ); return list.get(0); will work if list is a primitive; since you say that mapToObj() is applied on "a stream of primitives". ( and mapToObj() returns a Stream which also has no min() )
